# Class 'WP_Privacy_Requests_Table' not found

Tags: php, wp-admin

I have a WordPress website which is working great on front-end but I cannot access the wp-admin. Following is the link to the site http://www.promosaik-interlanguage.com/

I get following error while accessing the wp-admin

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Privacy_Requests_Table' not found in /var/www/vhosts/222/1106088/webspace/httpdocs/promosaik-interlanguage.com/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-privacy-data-export-requests-list-table.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/222/1106088/webspace/httpdocs/promosaik-interlanguage.com/wp-admin/includes/admin.php(79): require_once() #1 /var/www/vhosts/222/1106088/webspace/httpdocs/promosaik-interlanguage.com/wp-admin/admin.php(92): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...') #2 /var/www/vhosts/222/1106088/webspace/httpdocs/promosaik-interlanguage.com/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/222/1106088/webspace/httpdocs/promosaik-interlanguage.com/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-privacy-data-export-requests-list-table.php on line 19

Comment: Can you share more details ? Did you upgraded wordpress recently or modified any files inside wp-admin ?

Comment: Class '`WP_Privacy_Requests_Table`' is included in wordpress install package in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-privacy-requests-table.php`.

Can you check via FTP if this file exists ?

Comment: Yes the file exists but it is empty

Comment: You can download the WP package of the version that's installed on your site and replace this file on your server with file from the original package.